# Fusion Chain Reaction

Tags: nuclear-physics

Why we can't make chain reaction in fusion or we can't use fusion products .

Deuterium $-$ Helium$-3 $ fusion :
$$2D + 3He → 4He + 1p + 18.3 \text {MeV}$$ (I found in Wikipedia)

If we can do the above reaction can we use this proton energy to make another reaction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usable energy of fusion is in the form of the kinetic energy of the charged products of the reaction, primarily. The chain reaction *can* occur, and this is the goal (in all systems, it is a goal of each target or pulse; in some systems, it is a goal for the overall operation as well - the sun is an example of the latter), but only if we can contain the products for

1. enough time
2. at high enough density, and
3. high enough temperature

to overcome the barriers (Coulomb) of subsequent reactions. This is very difficult since, when we add so much thermal energy to the components of the reaction, they all very quickly are driven *away* from one another.

This

1. decreases the time of interaction,
2. decreases the density, and
3. decreases the temperature,

all contrary to the goals stated above. This fact motivates all fusion research.